# case statement returns multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case-statement

I want to return multiple rows in case statement. is it possible? or is there any alternate way to do it?

```
select 
   case 
      when 3 = 1 
          then (select orderid from order_master where noOfInstallment = installmentPaid) 
      else 
          (select orderid from order_master where noOfInstallment <> installmentPaid) 
   END
```

Both sub queries returns multiple rows. Now above query showing following error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

```
 SELECT o.* FROM Order_Master as o Where 
   (
      ((@paymentStatus = 0) AND (o.noOfInstallment <> o.installmentPaid))
      OR 
      ((@paymentStatus=1) AND (o.noOfInstallment = o.installmentPaid)) 
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE in SQL Server is **not** a flow control statement (it's different than the `switch` statement in C#) - it's just used to return one of several possible values.

You need to use `IF` statements in T-SQL

```
IF 3 = 1
   select orderid from order_master where noOfInstallment = installmentPaid
ELSE
   select orderid from order_master where noOfInstallment <> installmentPaid
```

or something like this.

Comment: Actually i dont want to write multiple queries. I want use resultset of above query to another subquery.

Comment: @Abhi: you cannot use `CASE` in this way - it can return **a single value** only. If you have subqueries that might return more than one value - you cannot use `CASE` to handle this

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the case statement in a right way, please take alook at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx).

Can you manage with a query like this:

```
select orderid,  
   case 
      when (noOfInstallment = installmentPaid) then
        'equal'   
      else 
        'not equal'
   END
from order_master
```

Comment: My query is working fine when subquery returns only 1 row. but it fails when subquery returns multiple rows. Can you please give me exact way to write query?